# Function not working with async statement

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

First of all sorry for this beginner question.

I am using net Framework 4.5 and can not go higher [this is probably important]

Trying to change my file copy code from

private Void
to
private async void

Why? - Because as long as the copy loop runs the whole process locks up

I have read a bit into async and await but it still seems a bit mistifying for me.

Can anyone please help me?

This is the code in question:

```
 private async void CopyFilesRecursively(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
        {
            if (target.GetFiles().Length > 0)
            {
                DeleteFilesRecursively(target);
                CopyFilesRecursively(source, target);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in source.GetDirectories())
                {
                    CopyFilesRecursively(dir, target.CreateSubdirectory(dir.Name));
                }
                foreach (FileInfo file in source.GetFiles())
                {
                    progressPercentage = ++targetLength / (double)sourceLength;
                    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(progressPercentage * 100).ToString() + "%");
                    PB_MW_FileTransfer.Value = Convert.ToInt32(progressPercentage * 100);
                    file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, file.Name), true);
                }
            }
        }
```

I know I need to use await statement but no matter what I try it just gives me errors.

I tried background worker before but that is something I understand even less.

Please help me I am struggling so much with this.

just want to remind that Net Framework 4.5 is the one I use for various reasons [because of licensing]

Comment: Just adding `async` does not make your function execute asyncronously. I actually do not see anything async here (outside the keyword).

Comment: changed framework from 4. to 4.5 since we have 4.5 installed

Comment: @Fildor Yes I know I took out the await because no matter where I put them it didn't wokred that is why I put out my await. This is the basic code that i want to get working async but I have basically 0 idea where to put the await.

Comment: `private async Task ... ` + [Progress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) + async IO method. Or `Task.Run()` this method, passing in the Progress object.

Comment: @noobprogrammer No point in doing that, really.

Comment: there is a lot more involved in using async/await than simply adding keywords; you actually need to have an async implementation of the thing you want to do; but: `FileInfo` doesn't provide a `CopyToAsync`, so... you'd have to implement it all yourself...

Comment: @TiberiusMelanith I hate to break it to you, but it's not _that_ easy. If you want to `await` something, it actually needs to be awaitable.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for the info I feared as much. Any tips on where to start if I want to make a async file copy? I really want to make it work. It can not be that I am stuck at this point forever.

Comment: I cannot recommend Steven Cleary's Blogs enough on those topics: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html

Comment: @Fildor, that's the very opposite of "best practices". Please don't do that.

Comment: @Blindy Well, yes and no. If he wants to stick with framework 4.5 _and_ use async Task, he doesn't have much choice. I wouldn't necessarily do it, but it's possible. TAP over the "old" async as suggested in your answer is probably better, I agree. But still ... meh.

Comment: The point of `async` isn't to shove work on a threadpool thread, it's to not use a thread at all for the portions of your code that don't actually require the CPU (ie, file I/O). If all you do in your method is `Task.Run` and then hold that thread for half an hour, your solution would probably work in a college homework, but when used in an ASP.NET application it will kill the whole server, because it expects to be able to use the thread pool to service requests. So, no, that is the very opposite of best practices.

Comment: @Blindy. Yes, I already said, I agree. Not in whole with your last comment but in this case with the point being to become "truly" async, not "fake" async.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what part of licensing prevents you from using .NET Core?

Comment: @StephenCleary Sorry for the late reply, we have .net 4.5 which saved my project in the end. We can not use anything else because our subsystem is a tight super secure island and every single kind of software change needs to be approved my a multi national committee. that is why I can not simply use anything else if it is not already provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there it is me again, if anyone else has a similar problem in the future.

This is what I changed my code into. Here to share it took me quite a while and a friend helped me on a couple of occasions [like how to create sub folders etc]

```
 private async Task FolderCopyAsync(string source, string target)
        {
            foreach (string filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(source, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var targetFilename = target + filename.Substring(source.Length);
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(targetFilename));

                    using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(targetFilename))
                    {
                        await SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);
                    }
                }
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well for one thing you have to make your function return `Task`, because you're going to want to `await` it when you call it recursively. Plus every `async` function in general should be a `Task`, because presumably the point is that the caller needs to be able to `await` it.

As mentioned in the comments, just making a function `async` doesn't do anything by itself, you need to actually `await` other `async` functions for it to do anything. In particular for your case, you want to copy using [`FileStream.CopyToAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.copytoasync?view=netcore-3.1) -- ie, open the source stream in read mode, open the destination stream in write mode and `await` the copy method.

One point to notice is that `async` file I/O is .Net Core 3, you won't find it in .Net Framework. If you persist with using it, either don't use `async` at all, because the framework is not really built for it, or implement your own `async` file I/O with the provided `IAsyncResult` functions and `TaskCompletionSource` to signal the TPL when copying is done.

Answer (score 1):

> Why? - Because as long as the copy loop runs the whole process locks up

Your goal is to free up the UI thread.

> I tried background worker before but that is something I understand even less.

`BackgroundWorker` is quite dated at this point. Your modern options are:

1. Use `async` and `await`, calling asynchronous BCL I/O methods. Ideally, this would be the best solution; however, in this case (asynchronous file I/O), the BCL support is less than ideal.
2. Use `Task.Run`, which is a [modern replacement for `BackgroundWorker`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html). Note that you would not want to use this option on ASP.NET or other server environment.

Since you are on WinForms, `Task.Run` would be a perfect fit:

```
private void CopyFilesRecursively(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target) { ... }

// invoked as:
await Task.Run(() => CopyFilesRecursively(source, target));
```

Comment: Where "BCL" means [Base Class Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/framework-libraries#base-class-libraries), FYI, Tiberius